# (angular) Is there any performance improvement between input text event binding vs two way binding?

Tags: angular

I want to get data from my input text to a typescript variable. There's basically two ways to do this based on my googling (Do tell me if there are any cleaner methods).

### Method 1 - Event Binding

```
<input (input)="tbuser=$event.target.value" type="text">        

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  tbuser: string;
  someEvent() {
    console.log(this.tbuser);
}
```

### Method 2 - Two Way Binding

```
<input [(ngModel)]="tbuser" type="text">

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   tbuser: string;
   someEvent() {
      console.log(this.tbuser);                     
   }
```

Method 1 seems very clunky. The expression is long. Method two looks cleaner, but since it's two way binding, it may effect performace (especially if there are many inputs).

Is this so?
Are there any cleaner methods?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about something that involves user interaction, the performance difference is not going to be noticeable. Using the raw browser event is going to be milliseconds more performant over the two way binding but two way bind is a more convenient programming model. Method one is only one way bound when the user updates the input, model 2 will update the input if the component property changes.

It might affect how fast automated test run but no user will notice the difference.